# JavaScript Search For Certain String

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, search

I am trying to find a certain string within an array.

This is my code so far:

```
function getUserName(arrayName){
for (counter = 0 ; counter < arrayName.length ; counter++){
    check = arrayName[counter].search("Jon");

    if (check != -1){
          result = arrayName[counter];
    }               
    break;
  }
}
```

The problem that I am running into is that if there is a name above `Jon` in the array `(e.g Jon_111)` the result would be `Jon_111` and not `Jon`

What do I use to tell it to only find and return if it is exactly `Jon`.

Comment: instead of using search, why don't you simply do `arrayName[counter] === "Jon"`?

Comment: You can literally Google the title, and find multiple guides / questions on the same topic. Try Google first, next time.

Comment: @thomas sorry for my comment ... You are totally right with your dupe :)

Comment: Yeah, no problem. The `object` part of it is of course true, but it is still covered in the duplicate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` to find an array's element (or just `indexOf()`, depending on use case). To get an exact result only, use `===`

```
let index = arrayName.indexOf('Jon');
// or
let element = arrayName.find(e => e === 'Jon');
```

Comment: Ahh... I see now. Not used to seeing `===`, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just === ?

```
  function getUserName(arrayName){
for (counter = 0 ; counter < arrayName.length ; counter++){
    check = arrayName[counter]==="Jon";

    if (check === true){
          result = arrayName[counter];
    }               
    break;
  }
}
```